# Create URL which opens up a specific report type within report builder screen?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

The report builder page link looks like this for every report type:

/reportbuilder/reportType.apexp

For users that have the ability to create reports I'm wondering if it is possible to simplify the process for them by building custom "approved" report types and providing links to those reports which open directly on the report builder page.

Today there are a few issues: 1)it is not possible to hide report folders, 2) it is not possible to sort report types within folders, 3) the "Other Reports" folder contains too many reports, and 4) it is not possible to create a new report type folder.

If this is not possible, links to a specific report which a user could then edit (and save somewhere else) would work I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

All reports have a 15 digit ID just like object records in Salesforce. You should be able to create a custom link to the report by linking to your sf org and adding that 15 digit ID to the end.

This link will direct the user to the saved report which they can then customize and 'save as'.

Comment: Yes, this idea matches the last sentence in my question above.  It would work but I was hoping for a better solution.